# What is 'declare global' in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What is "declare global" and how is it possible ? I found this code inside Lodash typings. The problem is that when I try to replicate this into `my.d.ts` file exactly since global is not a namespace, module, function or var, I'm not allowed to do it. So question is how this declaration is possible in Typescript.

PS
So maybe there are some additional compiler options which will allow this?

```
declare global {
    interface Set<T> { }
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is not dependent on compiler settings. `declare global` is used inside a file that has `import` or `export` to declare things in the global scope. This is necessary in files that contain `import` or `export` since such files are considered modules, and anything declared in a module is in the module scope.

Using `declare global` in a file that is not a module (that is contains no `import`/`export`) is an error since everything in such a file is in the global scope anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have learned these principles through practice, but is there any official document to explain them？

Comment: @JohnHou As of now, there is https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation as well as https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html