# declare global, interface Window, window.name.init - in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have doubt regarding the following code. I can't understand what this means?

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        DD_LOGS: any;
    }
}
```

```
window.DD_LOGS.init({
       // Code for Datadog Log
    });
```

Can anyone help me understand this?
What does declare global, interface Window, window.DD_LOGS.init() do?

Comment: It's actually a code from reactjs project app.js file

Comment: It's [Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040272/what-is-declare-global-in-typescript)

Comment: @Teemu and not react as well

Comment: @Teemu I mean that he shouldn't add tag for React

Comment: @Masood OK, reactjs tag was not there when I left my first comment.

Comment: Masood Teemu sorry guys, I didn't knew it was typescript. My bad. So can you give me an idea on what this means?